# How to fill a combo box indirectly using address of some cell

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Suppose range("A1:A5") has some data in it. Range("A1:A5") is given a name group name "grp1".

Say range("B1") has a text `grp1` written into it.

Now if I want to access the content of group "grp1" indirectly using data validation.  I can write `=indirect("B1")` in the data validation address box. And I will get data of range("A1:A5") in the data validation.

Is it possible to do the same in a "Combo box"(active x control)

Answer (score 1):

In all the cells of the group MasterGroup you insert this code to have the value of the cell inside the group you have selected...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one group, inside ListFillRange you insert the name of grp1.
If you have more group you can make the same, creating a MasterGroup Range named for example GroupG, than you put it in the ListFillRange. After inside every cells of this group you insert :

```
 =INDIRECT($D$3)
```

In the cell D3 is wrhite the name of the group you want to use...
Changing the name change the data inside GroupG and then change data inside the Combo.

Comment: What is the meaning of: After inside every cells of this group you insert :  `=INDIRECT($D$3)`